# Difference between different  document ready handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready

N00b here.  Apologies in advance if this is a bad question.

What's the difference, *in effect*, between these two jQuery declarations, if any?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("I'm so loaded 1.");
});
```

and

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    alert("I'm so loaded 2.");
});
```

On a related note, why does this work ...

```
$(document).on('ready',function() {
    alert("I'm so loaded 3.");
});
```

... but this doesn't?

```
$('document').on('ready',function() {
    alert("I'm so loaded 4.");
});
```

Comment: `$('document')` is wrong, jquery just allows it to work in some versions.

Comment: Anything in 'quotes' is a selector; `$('document')` would typically look for a tag named `<document>` in this case.

Comment: Can we also add `$(function(){});` to the list which is also the same thing? The answer: There are multiple ways of doing things.

Comment: You might also want to look into the benefits of window.load

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.ready` method ignores the passed in selector because the only valid object it can be called on is the document. It isn't recommended to use `.on` or `.bind` with the `ready` event. Also, you should never use `'document'` because `document` is always available to you directly.

Comment: The method should be `$.ready` in my opinion, but it's way too far in the game to change that for jQuery.

Answer (score -1):

I've never seen it used as

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    alert("I'm so loaded 2.");
});
```

before and gathering from bjkeefe's comment and Kevin B's answer, it's not valid.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("I'm so loaded 1.");
});
```

Means once the page is fully loaded, execute the function. This is useful because then no jQuery will try to execute while the page is still loading and the particular element isn't loaded yet.

```
$(document).on('ready',function() {
    alert("I'm so loaded 3.");
});
```

The `on` function means that any events applied to a dynamically create element will still work as normal but I've never used `on` in this way before though so I can't guarantee that it would work in this scenario, I usually use `on` with something like `click`, `hover` etc. as what it does is make sure that any jQuery applied to dynamically created elements (elements created after the page has been loaded) will still work as without `on`, the jQuery would work on elements contained within the document normally but not on dynamically generated elements.

Comment: `.on` in this case is exactly the same as `$(document).ready()` other than the fact that it has to go into the .on method before it gets to the `.ready` method. The document can't be dynamically created later (it already exists) so event delegation is irrelevant.

Comment: cool, thanks @KevinB, I thought it looked weird and just didn't know what would actually happen in this instance.